# JQuery Datatables. Can't get JQuery function to work after AJAX load

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

Here is a screencast of the issue to make it clearer....

http://screencast.com/t/KXD8U1oA0yU6

This is my first project where I'm trying to get my head round AJAX so I am running into a few stumbling blocks.

I have a datatable that loads user details from a JSON output via AJAX.

There is a "Deactivate" button which deactivates the user account.

I have applied the popconfirm id to each row...

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#user_list').DataTable( {
                        stateSave: true,
                        "pageLength": 20,
                        "ajax": {
                            "url": "data/JSON_users_list.php",
                            "dataSrc": "",
                        },

                        "columns": [
                            { "data": "profile_photo_path" },
                            { "data": "namebulk" },
                            { "data": "email" },
                            { "data": "active" },
                            { "data": "id"}
                        ],
                        "columnDefs": [
                            { sClass: "hidden-xs hidden-sm", "targets": [ 0 ] },
                            { sClass: "user-name", "targets": [ 1 ] },
                            { sClass: "hidden-xs hidden-sm", "targets": [ 2 ] },
                            { sClass: "action-links", "targets": [ 3 ] },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 0 },
                            {
                            "targets": [ 4 ],
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": false
                        }
                        ],
                        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                              $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<div style="background: url(\''+aData.profile_photo_path+'\');" class="image-circle-50" id="'+aData.id+'-img"></div>');
                              $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a onclick="$(\'#menu\').load(\'USERS_edit.php?id='+aData.id+'\');" class="name edit" id="showmenu"><span id="'+aData.id+'-first_name">'+aData.first_name+'</span> <span id="'+aData.id+'-last_name">'+aData.last_name+'</span></a><span id="'+aData.id+'-username">'+aData.username+'</span>');

                              $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html('<a onclick="$(\'#menu\').load(\'USERS_edit.php?id='+aData.id+'\');" id="showmenu" class="edit"><i class="linecons-pencil"></i>Edit</a><a class="delete" id="deactivate"><i class="linecons-trash"></i>Deactivate</a>');

                              return nRow;
                        },
                    } );

                    var myTable = $('#user_list').DataTable();

                    yadcf.init(myTable, [
                        {column_number : 0, filter_type: 'none'},
                        {column_number : 1, filter_type: 'text'},
                        {column_number : 2, filter_type: 'text'}
                    ]);


                } );
            </script>
```

This is the specific line which should initialase the popconfirm

```
 <a class="delete" id="deactivate"><i class="linecons-trash"></i>Deactivate</a>
```

The popconfirm JS is found here: https://github.com/Ifnot/PopConfirm

Here is the code to initialise popconfirm on anything with the ID of "deactivate":

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Custom Title, Content and Placement
            $("#deactivate").popConfirm({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                content: "All previous records of this user will be maintained on the system for consistency",
                placement: "left",
                noBtn: "Cancel"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have tried changing it to:

**$('#main-content').ready(function() {**

and

**$('body').ready(function() {**

to make sure it is initialised for anything that appears in the body or the main-content DIV, but still no luck....

Am I missing something simple here, or is popconfirm natively not going to work like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this file in a script tag: jquery.popconfirm.js in your page? (see README on https://github.com/Ifnot/PopConfirm)

Comment: Yes indeed, I've gone through chrome's console and can see it, also - it works when not included in the AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

I think the script itself was inherently flawed in this regard, I tried another one http://flwebsites.biz/jConfirm/, and this worked flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'm going to leave this here for anyone facing this problem in the future.

Popconfirm doesn't work in this case because DataTables is asynchronous, so it is not neccesarily completed when `$(document).ready()` is called.

What you need to use is the `initComplete` callback, which is called when data has been fully loaded.

Here are the docs: https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete

In this case, you would have to do something like:

```
$('#user_list').DataTable({

  // Your initialization code

  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    $("#deactivate").popConfirm({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        content: "All previous records of this user will be maintained on the system for consistency",
        placement: "left",
        noBtn: "Cancel"
    });
  }
});
```